# Laravel 5.2 - validate value in array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to ensure a field is valid if the value appears in a predefined array, but it's not working for me.

The validation rule I am using is:

```
'title' => [
     'required',
     'in' => ['Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss', 'Ms'],
],
```

But it seems to pass validation if I enter an invalid value, such as "Dr".

Anyone know the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with a string validation rule instead of array:

```
'title' => 'required|in:Mr,Mrs,Miss,Ms';
```

Comment: it will work for one value and not work if the request yields an  array .. like checklist . if for other case than this .. this will work . 'title.*' => 'required|in:Mr,Mrs,Miss,Ms'